# sklearn.manifold import MDS No module named 'numpy.random.bit_generator'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, mds

I'm trying to set up an analysis pipeline to generate MDS figures. I imported what I think is necessary, but its resulting in an error:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.manifold import MDS
```

```
File "biasedurn.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.stats.biasedurn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random.bit_generator'
```

how should I resolve this?

Comment: You might try upgrading `scipy`.  It should be `numpy.random.Generator.bit_generator`.

Comment: Which version of numpy are you using?  You can check with `import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)`